# Show a log submission prompt after an iOS app crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm quite new to iOS app development, but back when developing desktop applications (both linux and windows), it's quite common to add a "guardian process" to check on the state of the main process and when the application crashes, a prompt is shown to let user choose whether to submit an error log and whether to restart the application.

It seems for Android apps, it's also possible to have a background service to check the state of a main application and when it crashes, a prompt is shown to let the user choose whether to share an error log or not.

Now I wonder if iOS apps can offer a similar functionality. So far it seems the crash reporting tools I'm aware of are just submitting error logs after the app crashed and started again by the user. Is it possible for an iOS app to show a "Your app has crashed, do you want to submit a crash log" prompt when it crashes? Or is this kind of feature simply technical impossible for the iOS platform?

Comment: The common approach is a catch-all with an NSExceptionHandler which can then, usually, without any UI, send a stack trace off the machine.  There are probably other services to handle these, but I know google has one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

Comment: @danh, I think an NSExceptionHandler only catches exceptions in the objective-c code, but not for c++ libraries and such? Also Crashlytics seem to only send logs at the start of the app after a crash. I'm wondering if it's possible to show an UI to prompt the user to choose whether to send logs or not, at the time of the crash, like in desktop apps and Android apps. AFAIK iOS don't allow background "guardian process" to apps, so I'm not sure if it's even technically possible to achieve this feature in iOS?